# Breaking a for loop as file download is completed

Tags: python

Here, I am trying to download an image from a list of urls (largest_images). I want to download just one image. As an image has downloaded successfully I want the for loop to be stopped immediately. I am having hard time figuring out where to put the break statement in the following code.

```
    for image_url in largest_images:
        # SOME VARIABLES
        timeout = 20
        response = None
        file_name = md5(image_url)
        file_path = os.path.join(dst_dir, file_name)
        try_times = 0    

        while True:
            try:
                try_times += 1
                response = requests.get(image_url, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    print "Downloading: %s" % image_url
                    with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
                        for chunk in response.iter_content(1024):
                            f.write(chunk)
                    response.close()
                    file_type = imghdr.what(file_path)
                    # if file_type is not None:
                    if file_type in ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "bmp"]:
                        new_file_name = "{}.{}".format(file_name,file_type)
                        new_file_path = os.path.join(dst_dir, new_file_name)
                        shutil.move(file_path, new_file_path)
                        print ("## OK: {} {}".format(new_file_name, image_url))
                        break (I have added a break statement here, but its not working)
                    else:
                        os.remove(file_path)
                        print ("## Err: {}".format(image_url))
                    break
            except Exception as e:
                if try_times < 3:
                    continue
                if response:
                    response.close()
                print ("## Fail: {} {}".format(image_url, e.args))
                break
```

Comment: Just take out the one in the except and keep the one in the try

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you try at most 3 times for each image_url. I suggest before going into the while loop, you ensure file_path is absent, and after you're done with the while loop, check if file exists in file_path. If a file exists, then break out from the for loop.